# How to call another function and catch the error in these two Functions?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-7.0

I wanted to combine the below script so that it can automatically replicate the AD database content without waiting for 15 minutes for all Online Domain controllers only.

```
function Replicate-AllDomainController
{
    (Get-ADDomainController -Filter *).Name | Foreach-Object { repadmin /syncall $_ (Get-ADDomain).DistinguishedName /e /A | Out-Null }; Start-Sleep 10; Get-ADReplicationPartnerMetadata -Target "$env:userdnsdomain" -Scope Domain | Select-Object Server, LastReplicationSuccess
}

function Test-AllDomainController
{
    $dcs = (Get-ADDomainController -Filter *).Name
    foreach ($items in $dcs)
    {
        Test-Connection $items -Count 1
    }
}

Try
{
    Where-Object (Test-AllDomainController)
    {
        Replicate-AllDomainController
    }
}
Catch
{
    Write-Output "Exception Type: $($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)"
    Write-Output "Exception Message: $($_.Exception.Message)"
}
```

How to do it properly so it will stop after the last AD DC has been replicated successfully with no issue?
If there is a problem, show the AD domain controllers with the problem in a separate Out-GridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot test this myself, but I think it is best to do the `try{}..catch{}` inside the function that calls on repadmin.exe.

Also, in that same function it would be simpler to test if the server can be reached with `Test-Connection`, so you can do both things with one function:

```
# create a list to collect errors
$errorList = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()

function Replicate-AllDomainController {
    (Get-ADDomainController -Filter *).Name | Foreach-Object { 
        # put the servername from the $_ automatic variable in a variable of your own, because when you
        # hit the catch block, inside there the $_ is the Exception object and no longer the server name.
        $dc = $_
        if (Test-Connection $dc -Count 1 -Quiet) {
            try {
                repadmin /syncall $dc (Get-ADDomain).DistinguishedName /e /A | Out-Null
            }
            catch {
                # the $errorList is available here using the script scope
                $script:errorList.Add(
                    [PsCustomObject]@{
                        'Server'            = $dc
                        'Exception Type'    = $_.Exception.GetType().FullName
                        'Exception Message' = $_.Exception.Message
                    }
                )
            }
        }
        else {
            Write-Warning "Server '$dc' cannot be reached"
        }
    }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
    Get-ADReplicationPartnerMetadata -Target "$env:userdnsdomain" -Scope Domain | Select-Object Server, LastReplicationSuccess
}

# call the function
Replicate-AllDomainController

# check if there were replication errors
if ($errorList.Count) {
    # if there were errors, show them in a separate GridView
    $errorlist | Out-GridView -Title "Replication errors"
}
else {
    Write-Host "All done; no errors reported" -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Theo, that does make sense and very straight forward.
May I know what's that Delay by 10 seconds is for?